# SELECT QUERY on a field that contain a list

Tags: sql, ms-access

as usual this is a really simple question.

I have a table that have a primary key. The thing is this primary key is sometime a list of unique ID seperated by comma(ex:1,2,3).

I want to do a SELECT on that table but I want to see one ID per row. Here is a simple example for the more visual one!

Data in the table :

```
1,2,3     Info1       Info2
```

What I want the SELECT query output :

```
1     Info1     Info2
2     Info1     Info2
3     Info1     Info2
```

Comment: This is not a simple question. Good chances are, you aren't getting an answer that you are going to like either: RDBMS don't like working with denormalized data all that much (not to mention that relational gods probably consider situations when a denormalized field is used as a **primary key** a serious blasphemy). Change your schema to normalized, otherwise you are in for a nightmare of maintenance.

Comment: Thank for the fast answer. You are right about the primary key thing. The thing is I actually rebuild the whole DB in the right way but now I only need to confirm that all the data is well imported.

Comment: My mistake for the RDBMS, well I dont want to tell something wrong so a have an Access database and I'm using VBA to execute some SQL. Andrew I know it really bad design like I said I'm working on a new model and I just want validate the data by doing this query on the old database.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming this is Oracle:**

```
WITH CTE
    AS (SELECT
             '1,2,3' AS COL1,
             'Info1' AS COL2,
             'Info2' AS COL3
        FROM
             DUAL)
SELECT
      REGEXP_SUBSTR ( COL1,
                   '[^,]+',
                   1,
                   RN )
          COL1,
      COL2,
      COL3
FROM
          CTE
      CROSS JOIN
          (SELECT
                ROWNUM RN
           FROM
                (SELECT
                       MAX ( LENGTH ( REGEXP_REPLACE ( COL1,
                                                '[^,]+' ) ) )
                       + 1
                           MAX_L
                 FROM
                       CTE)
           CONNECT BY
                LEVEL <= MAX_L)
WHERE
      REGEXP_SUBSTR ( COL1,
                   '[^,]+',
                   1,
                   RN )
          IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
      COL1;
```

**Results:**

```
1   Info1   Info2
2   Info1   Info2
3   Info1   Info2
```